# echo different fields in tabs

Tags: php, mysql, tabs

I'm trying to make a tab for my page, where each tab shows a different field of a mysql table row. I'd like to switch contents in the tab.
Every row has a different id, and I would like to make a tabbed design. The data should be chosen by the id of the table.
The tab works fine if i use just a simple text in the echo part, but I can't fetch the data from my database.
I tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

if (isset($data[0]) && is_numeric($data[0]) ) {
    $content = mysql_fetch_assoc ( mysql_query( "select id,tab_content_one,tab_content_two,tab_content_three,tab_content_four,tab_content_five from db_name where id = $data[0];") );
} else {
    $content = mysql_fetch_assoc ( mysql_query( "select id,tab_content_one,tab_content_two,tab_content_three,tab_content_four,tab_content_five from db_name order by id asc limit 1;") );   
}

switch($_GET['tabNum']) {
    case 1: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_one']); break;
    case 2: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_two']); break;
    case 3: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_three']); break;
    case 4: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_four']); break;
    case 5: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_five']); break;
}

?>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What do you get? Any errors?

Comment: any errors? You shouldn't use mysql_* functions because they are depracated and will be removed in future php relases. It seems that $content may not be visible in switch.

Comment: Check whether `$_GET['tabNum']` get any values or not. If `$_GET['tabNum']` getting value properly than check for `$content` array whether it is getting value in array . I think rest of think you done neat and clear.

Comment: No errors, it just simply shows nothing.

Comment: It shows no error message, it's just an empty area.
What do you, Robert mean, that $content is not visible in switch?
The tabs work fine if I just use: `case 2: echo "second tab content";`. So I'm pretty sure, that the problem is with the `$content`, but I don't know what to try.

Comment: what's in the `$data` variable? What's in the database? What is the result of each query when run from the mysql console? Did you try adding debug statement in your code?

Comment: the `$data` variable is just a two case variable, it can be 0 or 1, and if it's one, it shows a text.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to enclose the mysql_fetch_assoc into a while loop! For your code it will be something like this:

```
if (isset($data[0]) && is_numeric($data[0]) ) {
$sql = "select id,tab_content_one,tab_content_two,tab_content_three,tab_content_four,tab_content_five from db_name where id = $data[0];";
} else {
$sql = "select id,tab_content_one,tab_content_two,tab_content_three,tab_content_four,tab_content_five from db_name order by id asc limit 1;"; 
}
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    switch($_GET['tabNum']) {
    case 1: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_one']); break;
    case 2: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_two']); break;
    case 3: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_three']); break;
    case 4: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_four']); break;
    case 5: echo strip_tags($content['tab_content_five']); break;
}
}
```

Anyway it's suggested to you as mysql_fetch_assoc it's going to be deprecated starting from php 5.5.0 to use the mysql_PDO extension instead.

Comment: Of course I'm assuming you've tested your sql statement and $_GET['tabNum'] always have a value which is 1 2 3 4 or 5.

Comment: Yes, the values are 1,2, 3,4,5 but somehow, it doesn't work.
it shows nothing in every tab, I tried that I use 'strip_tags($content['tab_content_one'])', only on the first case, but still the whole tab doesn't show anything.

Comment: Add this tests: (ups) after every $sql print($sql); after result add print(mysql_affected_rows()); and inside the while print_r($content); so you can see where the error is

Comment: I have no error message to this test and it shows nothing again, but maybe I have some misunderstanding in where to add these lines.

Comment: I tried this:
`<?php

if (isset($data[0]) && is_numeric($data[0]) ) {
 $sql = mysql_fetch_assoc ( mysql_query( "select id,tab_content_one,tab_content_two,tab_content_three,tab_content_four,tab_content_five from db_name where id = $data[0];") );
 print($sql);
} else {
 $sql = mysql_fetch_assoc ( mysql_query( "select id,tab_content_one,tab_content_two,tab_content_three,tab_content_four,tab_content_five from db_name order by id asc limit 1;") );
print($sql); 
}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
print(mysql_affected_rows());

while($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
print_r($content);

}
?>`

Comment: LOL man, re-read the first answer, it's 
`if (blah blah blah) { $sql = "SQL-STATEMENT;";}`
not
`if (blah...) {$sql = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SQL-STATEMENT;";));}`

all those mysql_ functions on the if else clause are wrong.

Comment: Lol, I should probably eat something, because I lost the ability of thinking :D

Comment: I tried to add the print things but it showd the sql-statements in all tabs, but no error messages.